# java.lang.NullPointerException while saving bulk documents to couchdb using couchdb4j api in java

Tags: java, database, nosql, couchdb

I tried to save document consisting around 1,30,000 records, and I used the bulksavedocument method to save the document, but I am getting the following error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fourspaces.couchdb.Database.bulkSaveDocuments(Database.java:280)
```

Here is the code I used to save bulk documents.

```
JSONArray json=new JSONArray(); 
Document[] newdoc = null;
newdoc = new Document[json.size()];                      
for(int i=0;i<json.size();i++)
{
    Document singleDoc = new Document(json.getJSONObject(i));
    newdoc[i]=singleDoc;
}         
Session s = new Session("localhost",5984);
Database db = s.getDatabase("test"); 

db.bulkSaveDocuments(newdoc);
```

when I tried to debug the program along with the source code getting the following error

```
   net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of {"db_name":"item_masters_test","doc_count":0,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":0,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":79,"instance_start_time":"1337249297703950","disk_format_version":5,"committed_update_seq":0}
at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:499)
at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromJSONTokener(JSONArray.java:1116)
at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromString(JSONArray.java:1197)
at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:127)
at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:105)
at com.fourspaces.couchdb.CouchResponse.getBodyAsJSONArray(CouchResponse.java:129)
at com.fourspaces.couchdb.Database.bulkSaveDocuments(Database.java:282)
at ItemMasterTest4.main(ItemMasterTest4.java:565)
```

Please suggest the solution to get rid of this exception.

Comment: @ckuetbach * slaps forehead *

Comment: not line 280 of the resultset, of course line 280 of the sourcecode. I think it is Document singleDoc = new Document..., but I don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know really well this JSON lib, but this

```
JSONArray json=new JSONArray();
```

is probably an array with size 0 (empty).

So your loop enters with index 0, that does'nt exists. So

```
json.getJSONObject(i)
```

propably returns null.

---

Where you write this

```
for(int i=0;i<json.size();i++)
```

You probably mean that

```
for(int i=0;i<json.size()-1;i++)
```

Comment: No Database is NOT null. There would be a different StackTrace then. There is a access of Database in line 280. There is a null pointer.

Comment: My bad; that went absolutely over my head.  I need to sleep, haha.

Comment: i changed the code with                                           for(int i=0;i<json.size()-1;i++) it didn't work.

Comment: com.fourspaces.couchdb.Database.bulkSaveDocuments(Database.java:280) https://github.com/mbreese/couchdb4j/blob/master/src/java/com/fourspaces/couchdb/Database.java

Comment: Without further info from the OP about CoucheDB4j version we cannot refer to this source line for shure. But is a good direction ...

Comment: the couchdb4j version is couchdb4j-0.3.0